# How to lock and modify a dictionary safety per unit 'group'

Tags: python, python-2.7, thread-safety

The following code is not my real code. I made it simple for asking this question.
This is a server side code of a web application.

What I want to do is locking group when it is modified but I don't know how.
For example, a user who belongs to 'GroupA' posted a request to the server, and I want to add the user_id to the dictionary of 'GroupA' safety.
I want to lock only the dictionary which 'GroupA' contains. I don't want to lock the dictionary 'groups' contains.
Because users who belongs to 'GroupB' never modify the dictionary which 'GroupA' contains
Please give me advise.

```
# this dictionary is mutable which means new groups could be added anytime
groups = {'GroupA': {}, 'GroupB': {}, 'GroupC': {}}


def request_handler(request):
    # Assuming these come from the user's http post
    user_id = request.userid
    user_group = request.user_group

    group = groups[user_group]  # a group contains user_id's dictionary
    if user_id in group:
        # the value of the key 'user_id' is the number of the user's post
        group[user_id] = group[user_id] + 1
    else:
        group.append(user_id)
        group[user_id] = 1
```

Comment: Can't you just use a [`threading.Lock()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=lock#threading.Lock) to control access to each group's sub-dictionary?

Comment: I don't know how I could use the lock object which threading.Lock() generates, not affecting to threads of other groups.

Comment: Before operating on a sub-dictionary, you would need to call `lock.acquire()` and have it block until any other threads that already have control call `lock.release()`. See the documentation about [Lock Objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html?highlight=lock#lock-objects). I think doing this implies that each sub-dictionary will need its own `Lock` object. It's often convenient to acquire a lock by using a `with` statement on one before an indented block of code that accesses the resource, because they're also proper Python context managers.

Comment: 'each sub-dictionary will need its own Lock object' aha! thank you martineau!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a separate lock for each group. E.g.:

```
groups = {'GroupA': (Threading.Lock(), {}), 'GroupB': (Threading.Lock(), {})}


def request_handler(request):
    # Assuming these come from the user's http post
    user_id = request.userid
    user_group = request.user_group

    glock, group = groups[user_group]
    with glock:
        group[user_id] = group.get(user_id, 0) + 1
```

If the groups are also dynamic, you will need a lock for `groups` as well which must be acquired before any groups are added or removed.

Consider other approaches:

1. Use your own mapping classes for groups that subclass dict and use locks appropriately.
2. Have a single thread responsible for reading and updating groups. Have other threads send tasks to it through a pair of [`Queue`s](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). (Now you don't need locking at all.)